# How to add footerview to MvxListView

Tags: android-listview, mono, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am using MvxListView in MVVMCross https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross
I add FooterView to MvxListView as following:

```
 LayoutInflater _inflatorservice = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        View view = _inflatorservice.Inflate(Resource.Layout.footer_layout,null,false);
        listView.AddFooterView(view);
```

But I can't see the footer view in ListView when I run the application.
How can I display footer view in MvxListView?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the footer before the Adapter is set?

This was raised in an issue - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/331

The fix was to allow advanced users to inherit a custom control (see N=18 in [N+1 days of MvvmCross](http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com)) which inherits from MvxListView and which passes `null` down as the Adapter in the constructor. The custom control then needs to set the footer view and then set the MvxAdapter.

This isn't something I've personally done - but the feedback was that this worked.